# How to setup HaxeFlixel VSCode Project Configuration on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, haxeflixel

I've been having issues with the HaxeFlixel VSCode setup. I couldn't make the HashLink/Debug menu appear on VSCode, and I also couldn't do step 4 because when I put this command in my terminal:

```
 flixel configure C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\flixel-demos\git -ide vscode
```

I get this error:

```
Called from ? line 1
Called from FlxTools.hx line 136
Called from FlxTools.hx line 15
Called from a C function
Called from FlxTools.hx line 79
Called from massive/sys/cmd/CommandLineRunner.hx line 109
Called from massive/sys/cmd/CommandLineRunner.hx line 258
Called from commands/ConfigureCommand.hx line 31
Called from C:\Users\Jens\GitHub\haxe\std/neko/_std/sys/FileSystem.hx line 50
Uncaught exception - std@file_full_path
```

Can someone show me how to properly set it up for my operating system?

The directory I was using in my terminal:

[image: Linux Directory Image]

Tutorial I was using:
https://haxeflixel.com/documentation/visual-studio-code/

Comment: It would be good to know exactly what your issue is. I've put a little video on YT explaining my setup https://youtu.be/EGR0F235aMw but if you are able to share the error message you have I'd be able to help you more.

Comment: @richbray89 I clarified my question.

Comment: Ah I see. Can you confirm you are using these versions:
- Haxe 4.1.5
- flixel 4.8.1
- lime 7.8.0
- openfl 9.0.2

Also, step 4 is an optional step. You should be able to create a Flixel game without doing it

Comment: @richbray89 I am using all of those versions. I installed haxe using lix then downgraded them so it would work.

Comment: @richbray89 I think I've fixed my problem somehow. I think I wasn't doing the steps properly. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by re-installing and re-doing the whole process. I'm not sure what the issue was but it's fixed now :).

Comment: Ah nice, glad you managed to get it fixed 